# Disk full, how to move mysql database files?

Tags: mysql, database

my database files located in `/var/lib/mysql` which located in partition `/dev/sda5`

this partition is full ([refer here for details](https://serverfault.com/questions/215179/centos-100-disk-full-how-to-remove-log-files-history-etc))

so I'm going to move the location of database files from `/var/lib/mysql` to `/home/lib/mysql`

What is the right way to move this database files?

Im going to do this steps:

1. Stop http server and PHP
2. Change `datadir=/var/lib/mysql` to
   become `datadir=/home/lib/mysql` in
   `/etc/my.cnf`
3. move all database files to the new
   location
4. run `killall -9 mysql`, then
   `/etc/init.d/mysqld start`
5. Start http server and PHP

Is this right? Correct me if I'm wrong

**added:**

currently, mysql won't stop. refer here: [mysql wont stop, mysqld_safe appeared in top](https://serverfault.com/questions/214922/mysql-wont-stop-mysqld-safe-appeared-in-top)

Answer (score 2):

1- You should stop the mysql server (step 4) before moving the files (step 3).

2- You should stop it gracefully not using `kill -9` unless needed to.

3- I think you mean start in step 5. (I edit the question).

4- You need also to check the files permissions and ownership.

Comment: currently, mysql won't stop. refer here: http://serverfault.com/questions/214922/mysql-wont-stop-mysqld-safe-appeared-in-top

Answer (score 0):

1. stop http server and PHP
2. login as root into mysql and "flush tables" (if flush fails you will have some tables to repair)
3. run killall -9 mysql
4. Change datadir=/var/lib/mysql to become datadir=/home/lib/mysql in /etc/my.cnf
5. move all database files to the new location
6. start mysql server
7. check tables status (from phpmyadmin or other gui)
8. start http server and PHP

Comment: That should be a **very last resort** for shutting down a mysql server - first step would be to **carefully** examine everything on sda5 to see if anything can be deleted or removed temporarily.

Comment: why need "flush tables"?

Comment: Kopeklan wrote: currently, mysql won't stop. Flush tables: for write any cache before kill mysql.